# Duplicate removal not working on table with many NULLs

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Perhaps I've been staring at the screen too long but I have the following [legacy] table I'm messing with:

```
describe t3_test;
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| provnum            | varchar(24)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| trgt_mo            | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mcare              | varchar(2)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| bed2prsn_asst      | varchar(2)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| trnsfr2prsn_asst   | varchar(2)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tlt2prsn_asst      | varchar(2)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| hygn2prsn_asst     | varchar(2)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| bath2psrn_asst     | varchar(2)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ampmcare2prsn_asst | varchar(2)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| any2prsn_asst      | varchar(2)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| n                  | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pct                | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| trgt_qtr           | varchar(12)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| recno              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| enddate            | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have data that looks like this..

```
"555223","2008-10-01 00:00:00",NULL,"1",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"40","93.0233","2008Q4","5767343","2008-12-31"
"555223","2008-10-01 00:00:00",NULL,"1",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"40","93.0233","2008Q4","4075309","2008-12-31"
"555223","2008-10-01 00:00:00",NULL,"0",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"3","6.97674","2008Q4","4075308","2008-12-31"
"555223","2008-10-01 00:00:00",NULL,"0",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"3","6.97674","2008Q4","5767342","2008-12-31"
"555223","2008-10-01 00:00:00","N",NULL,"1",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"36","83.7209","2008Q4","4075327","2008-12-31"
"555223","2008-10-01 00:00:00","N","1",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"36","83.7209","2008Q4","4075323","2008-12-31"
"555223","2008-10-01 00:00:00","Y","1",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"4","9.30233","2008Q4","4075325","2008-12-31"
"555223","2008-10-01 00:00:00",NULL,NULL,"0",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"3","6.97674","2008Q4","4075310","2008-12-31"
"555223","2008-10-01 00:00:00",NULL,NULL,"1",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"40","93.0233","2008Q4","4075311","2008-12-31"
```

The first two lines of the table clearly appear to be dupes (minus the A.I. index "recno"). I've tried a half dozen dupe-removal routines and they are not automatically removed.

At this point I am not sure what exactly is wrong?  Is it possible there's an invisible character somewhere?  Is it possible a letter is in a different character encoding?  When I dump the data to CSV as is listed, it doesn't look any different.

Do you have a delete routine that would work on this file structure that would remove anything that is a dupe (minus the recno field)?  I have been staring at this for two days and for some reason, it escapes me.  (btw, I am aware of the column name anomaly for bathd2psrn_asst - that's not it)

This (original) table has over 13 million records in it.  And is over 3GB in size so I'm looking for the most efficient way to kill dupes.. Any ideas?

Here's an example of one of the dupe-killing techniques I used that did not work:

```
DELETE a FROM t3_test as a, t3_test as b WHERE
(a.provnum=b.provnum)
AND (a.trgt_mo=b.trgt_mo OR a.trgt_mo IS NULL AND b.trgt_mo IS NULL)
AND (a.mcare=b.mcare OR a.mcare IS NULL AND b.mcare IS NULL)
AND (a.bed2prsn_asst=b.bed2prsn_asst OR a.bed2prsn_asst IS NULL AND b.bed2prsn_asst IS NULL)
AND (a.trnsfr2prsn_asst=b.trnsfr2prsn_asst OR a.trnsfr2prsn_asst IS NULL AND b.trnsfr2prsn_asst IS NULL)
AND (a.tlt2prsn_asst=b.tlt2prsn_asst OR a.tlt2prsn_asst IS NULL AND b.tlt2prsn_asst IS NULL)
AND (a.hygn2prsn_asst=b.hygn2prsn_asst OR a.hygn2prsn_asst IS NULL AND b.hygn2prsn_asst IS NULL)
AND (a.bath2psrn_asst=b.bath2psrn_asst OR a.bath2psrn_asst IS NULL AND b.bath2psrn_asst IS NULL)
AND (a.ampmcare2prsn_asst=b.ampmcare2prsn_asst OR a.ampmcare2prsn_asst IS NULL AND b.ampmcare2prsn_asst IS NULL)
AND (a.any2prsn_asst=b.any2prsn_asst OR a.any2prsn_asst IS NULL AND b.any2prsn_asst IS NULL)
AND (a.n=b.n OR a.n IS NULL AND b.n IS NULL)
AND (a.pct=b.pct OR a.pct IS NULL AND b.pct IS NULL)
AND (a.trgt_qtr=b.trgt_qtr OR a.trgt_qtr IS NULL AND b.trgt_qtr IS NULL)
AND (a.enddate=b.enddate OR a.enddate IS NULL AND b.enddate IS NULL)
AND (a.recno>b.recno);
```

Comment: I'm wondering if having lots of NULL values interfere's with the routine's ability to detect dupes?   NULL does not equal NULL right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of this scenario, the problem was not with the SQL statement.  It was a problem with the DATA, but it was not visible.

The two fields designated type "float" held hidden decimal values that were slightly different from each other.  Converting those fields to DECIMAL(a,b) type made the dupes show up and be properly deleted by conventional means.

Special thanks to Gordon Linoff for suggesting looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

For such a large table, `delete` can be quite inefficient -- all the logging needed for the deletes is very cumbersome.

I might recommend that you try the `truncate`/`insert` approach:

```
create table temp_t3_test as (
     select provnum, targ_mo, . . .,
            min(recno) as recno,
            enddate
     from t3_test
     group by provnum, targ_mo, . . ., enddate;

truncate table t3_test;

insert into t3_test(provnum, targ_mo, . . . , recno, enddate)
    select *
    from temp_t3_test;
```

Comment: I ran the first statement

Comment: Here's what I got:   https://i.imgur.com/nxACivA.png

it still created dupes in the temp file.

Comment: This is the statement I ran:  create table t3_new as (
  select
    provnum,trgt_mo,mcare,bed2prsn_asst,trnsfr2prsn_asst,tlt2prsn_asst,hygn2prsn_asst,bath2psrn_asst,ampmcare2prsn_asst,any2prsn_asst,n,pct,trgt_qtr,min(recno),enddate
  from t3_test
  group by
    provnum,trgt_mo,mcare,bed2prsn_asst,trnsfr2prsn_asst,tlt2prsn_asst,hygn2prsn_asst,bath2psrn_asst,ampmcare2prsn_asst,any2prsn_asst,n,pct,trgt_qtr,enddate
   )

Comment: I am trying to figure out what's wrong?  reserved word conflict?  odd foreign character set in a field?  or some stupid omission?  It escapes me.

Comment: @TrentThree . . . Presumably you have an issue with floating point numbers (say `pct`) that look the same but differ in some very small way.  You might convert the decimal numbers to a decimal type (say `decimal(10, 4)`) for the aggregation.

Comment: Yes, the problem was the result of the FLOAT values

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE t3_new AS 
         ( 
                  SELECT   provnum, 
                           trgt_mo, 
                           mcare, 
                           bed2prsn_asst, 
                           trnsfr2prsn_asst, 
                           tlt2prs‌​n_asst, 
                           hygn2prsn_ass‌​t, 
                           bath2psrn_asst, 
                           amp‌​mcare2prsn_asst, 
                           any2‌​prsn_asst, 
                           n, 
                           pct, 
                           trgt‌​_qtr, 
                           Min(recno), 
                           endd‌​ate 
                  FROM     t3_test 
                  GROUP BY provnum, 
                           trgt_mo, 
                           mcare, 
                           bed2prsn_asst, 
                           trnsfr2prsn_asst, 
                           tlt2prs‌​n_asst, 
                           hygn2prsn_ass‌​t, 
                           bath2psrn_asst, 
                           amp‌​mcare2prsn_asst, 
                           any2‌​prsn_asst, 
                           n, 
                           pct, 
                           trgt‌​_qtr,
                           enddate

         )
```

When you use min(recno), you don't actually select just one row. you select the minimum of all recno and use the same value for all the rows. To remove less rows, you can use distinct or group by as I have used. I would say that you can remove the rec no from the temp table and use a new auto increment column in the table that you create again to avoid gaps in the ids.

This is to be used in with the method suggested by Gordon Linoff.

Comment: Tried this, and it also created the dupes in the t3_new table.

Comment: What columns are duplicated? Make sure you add those to the group by column.

Comment: I added all of them to it and there still appears to be an issue.. Is there a problem using group by or doing equality/testing with columns that are NULL?  I cannot seem to solve this.. any known bugs in MariaDB on this issue?

Comment: GROUP BY shouldn't have duplicates. It doesn't make sense. Because if there are duplicates then it didn't group by it. Could it be different by some characters? Like "Name" vs "Name ". Can you post some examples to show what's going on?